# Get CLR Type of Segments in an InvocationExpressionSyntax

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

I've extracted all `InvocationExpressionSyntax`'s from a parsed C# script with results like:

```
1. System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\").First()
2. Math.Sin(3).ToString()
3. value.Substring(0, 1)
```

I also have the SemanticModel object and have searched and experimented in various ways to do the following:

1. Iterate from the last to the first invocation call and determine which CLR type it belongs to. As an example, `Math.Sin(3).ToString()` should tell me that the method is `ToString` while the type is `Double`. In the next iteration the method would be `Sin` and the Type would be `Math`.
2. In order to do the above, I have a hard-coded list of types `List<Type> Allowed`. I now want to extract the `CLR Type` of each segment of the `InvocationExpressionSyntax` and see if it is included in the whitelist.

The objective is to white-list types and calls to a small subset that end-users can utilize. Example, `Math.XXX` is ok, `Directory.XXX` is not.

I have searched around and experimented quite a bit but have not figured out how to extract a `Type` object against each expression. Expected types of course are `MethodInfo`, `PropertyInfo` and `Class`.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(invocationExpression)`?

Comment: What do you mean with "Expected types of course are MethodInfo, PropertyInfo and Class." ? Sounds like expected types should be `IMethodSymbol` and `INamedTypeSymbol`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the NDepend code querying model?
https://www.ndepend.com/features/cqlinq#CQL
https://www.ndepend.com/docs/cqlinq-features
https://www.ndepend.com/docs/cqlinq-syntax

For example you can write the code query:

```
let blackListedMethodNames = new [] {
  "System.IO.Directory.XXX",
  ...
}.ToHashSet()

let blackListedMethods =
Methods.Where(m => blackListedMethodNames.Contains(m.FullName)).ToHashSet()

from m in Application.Methods.UsingAny(blackListedMethods )
select new { m, 
             blackListedMethodsCalled = m.MethodsCalled.Intersect(blackListedMethods ) }
```

for example:

[image: NDepend code query to black list some method]